# HXT -- what is "deep"?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I'm putting in a lot of time trying to figure out how to use HXT. I keep coming against examples using `deep`. What does `deep` do?

For example, [this code](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Practical/Simple2) has the following:

```
atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)
```

[Another example:](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Practical/Google1)

```
-- case-insensitive tag matching
atTagCase tag = deep (isElem >>> hasNameWith ((== tag') . upper . localPart))
  where tag' = upper tag
        upper = map toUpper
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#v:deep

> ```
> deep :: Tree t => a (t b) c -> a (t b) cSource
> ```
>
> recursively searches a whole tree for subtrees, for which a predicate holds. The search is performed top down. When a tree is found, this becomes an element of the result list. The tree found is not further examined for any subtress, for which the predicate also could hold. See `multi` for this kind of search.
>
> example: `deep isHtmlTable` selects all top level table elements in a document (with an appropriate definition for `isHtmlTable`) but no tables occuring within a table cell.

You could find the documentation given a function name or type signature with [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) or [Hayoo!](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=%22deep%22)

---

Basically, if the XML tree is like

```
<p>
    <strong id="a">
       <em id="b">
          <strong id="c">
             foo
          </strong>
       </em>
    </strong>
    <ins id="d">
       <strong id="e">
          bar
       </strong>
       <em id="f">
          baz
       </em>
    </ins>
</p>
```

`deep (isElem >>> hasName "strong") tree` will return a list for

```
<strong id="a">
<strong id="e">
```

because we can find these two `<strong>`s when walking into the tree, while `(isElem >>> hasName tag) tree` will return an empty list because the root of the tree is a `<p>`, not a `<strong>`

Comment: Thanks. I've read the documentation, but I don't grok it. For example, what is the difference between (isElem) and (deep isElem)?

Comment: @Muchin: `isElem` and `hasName tag` only checks the top level. `deep` makes these arrows apply recursively to all levels.

Comment: Comparing `deep` with `deepest` it sounds like `deep` should be rather renamed `shallow`.  I guess it's a depth-first but short circuits from the top, vs `multi` which searches through all, and `deepest` which starts bottom-up?